# How can I typeset a group action?

Tags: align, nesting

How would I typeset something that looks like the following?

[image]

I have tried

```
\begin{align*}
    \sigma : T^k(V) & \longrightarrow T^k(V) \\
                  T & \longmapsto
    \begin{aligned}
        \sigma T : V \times \dots \times V & \longrightarrow \mathbb R \\
        (v_1, \dots, v_k) & \longmapsto T(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(k)})
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

However, this gives something that looks more like:

[image]

Note the vertical alignment of the `T \longmapsto` in the second version.

Comment: It took me a while to see the difference between the two drawing. There is an optionnal argument to the `aligned` environment. Try `\begin{aligned}[t]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `[t]` option of the `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \sigma \colon T^k(V) & \longrightarrow T^k(V) \\
                  T & \longmapsto
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        \sigma T \colon V \times \dots \times V & \longrightarrow \mathbb R \\
        (v_1, \dots, v_k) & \longmapsto T(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(k)})
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To be fussy: I'd replace `:` (relation) by `\colon` (punctuation, more or less). The latter has the correct spacing for a mapping.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It does look a little better.

Answer (score 6):

I would simply use an `alignedat` environment, and the `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools`. I think the layout will look better if the last line is closer to the secng than the latter from the first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \sigma \colon T^k(V) & \longrightarrow \mathrlap{T^k(V)} \\
                  T & \longmapsto& \sigma T \colon V \times \dots \times V & \longrightarrow \mathbb R \\[-0.8ex]
         && (v_1, \dots, v_k) & \longmapsto T(v_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, v_{\sigma(k)})
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, very nice. Sadly I can only accept one answer.

Comment: That is really unimportant. The main point is that you feel my proposal as useful.